# External domains links allowed in canonical tag?

Tags: canonical-url, rel-canonical

I have two websites A and B and i want to right now add A website link in B website as a canonical URL. It's allowed in SEO? It's is best for SEO?

Answer (score 2):

Sure is allowed, and recommended too.

Edit: Reference I guess at https://powerdigitalmarketing.com/blog/using-relcanonical-tag/

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.   This could be improved by telling how you know this.   Do you have references?  Can you share personal experience?

Comment: I mean, it was a very straight-forward question?

Comment: Thank you for adding the reference. It makes a big difference.